# Dynamic linq query with dynamic where conditions and from conditions

Tags: linq, entity-framework, ef-code-first

```
public GetApplicants(string Office,
                         int Id,
                         List<int> cfrparts,
                         List<int> expertiseAreaIds,
                         List<int> authIds,
                         List<int> specIds)
    {
        bool isAuthIdsNull = authIds == null;
        authIds = authIds ?? new List<int>();
        bool isSpecIdNull = specIds == null;

enter code here
     var query =
            from application in Apps
            from cfr in application.cfr
            from exp in cfr.Aoe
           from auth in exp.Auth
            from spec in exp.Special

            where application.Design.Id == 14
            where  (iscfrpart || cfrPartIds.Contains(cfr.CfrP.Id))
            where (isexp || expertiseAreaIds.Contains(exp.Aoe.Id))
            where (isAuthIdsNull || authIds.Contains(auth.Auth.Id))
            where  (isSpecIdNull || specIds.Contains(spec.Special.Id))
            where application.Office.Text.Contains(Office)
            where application.D.Id == Id

            select application.Id;
```

How can i make this query dynamic. If I have only Id and Office values It should still give me the resultset based on the avaliable values. Cureently its not giving me the result.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing multiple calls to `where`, use `&&`

```
 var query =
        from Apps
        where (iscfrpart || cfrPartIds.Contains(Apps.cfr.CfrP.Id))
        && (isexp || expertiseAreaIds.Contains(Apps.cfr.Aoe.Id))
        && (isAuthIdsNull || authIds.Contains(Apps.cfr.Aoe.Auth.Id))
        && (isSpecIdNull || specIds.Contains(Apps.cfr.Aoe.Special.Id))
        && Apps.Office.Text.Contains(Office)
        && Apps.D.Id == Id

        select application.Id;
```

Additionally, this clause `application.D.Id == 14` will cause 0 results when combined with this one: `application.D.Id == Id` if the passed in Id does not equal 14. You may want to delete that first clause.

Edit: updated your from clause, but I still don't think this will work because your table structure seems off.

Comment: Hi, Than you for replying. I have made the requested change but still i dont get any results if cfrIds,expertiseareaIds,authIds,specIds are null. I want the query to pull the data based on designId, office, Id if others are null.

Comment: I just noticed your from statement is all messed up. Let me update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic querying isn't required to solve this problem.  You can write code that constructs the query.

Make a method that constructs your filter based on the information you have.

```
public Expression<Func<Application, bool>> GetFilterForCFR(List<int> cfrParts)
{
  if (cfrParts == null || !cfrParts.Any())
  {
    return app => true;
  }
  else
  {
    return app => app.cfr.Any(cfr => cfrParts.Contains(cfr.cfrPId));
  }
}
```

Then, you can construct the query using the expression.

```
var query = Apps;
var cfrFilter = GetFilterForCFR(cfrParts);
query = query.Where(cfrFilter);

//TODO apply the other filters

var finalquery = query.Select(app => app.Id);
```